# how do you call this anti-pattern?

Tags: anti-patterns

In the database you have a table with a bit field, let call that field **Active**

In the application you have a variable boolean, let call it **NotActive**

Everytime you get the field from the table, in the application you have switch the meaning of the variable.

```
NotActive = !mytable.active;
```

Another example would be a bit field in the database named **Enable__yes__no** and in the code you do

```
control.enabled = !mytable.Enable_yes_no
```

best practice would be to keep the same name and the same meaning, but the pattern above, how to you call that?

Comment: This isn't a pattern. Patterns are descriptions of best practice in a variety of situations. This is poor programming, an anti-pattern at best.

Comment: changed tag and title to anti-pattern

Comment: @Sinan, I will rollback your modification because I edited my question at the same time. Just update my updated question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't name boolean variables with a negative prefix.

Name the variable IsActive or Active, naming it NotActive is **double negation**.

Edit/Clarification:

If you need to check if the thing is active, you need a double negation:

```
If (!NotActive) { DoSomething() }
```

Positive boolean Variable names are much easier to understand:

```
If (isActive) { DoSomething() }
```

Comment: Double Negotiation? Do you mean Double Negation?

Comment: +1: I was also going to say this.  Calling a variable NotXXX is the bad pattern.  Good point.  A better name would be Disabled.

Comment: Just rename the variable IsNotNotActive. Now the logic is positive again.

Comment: NotActive is not a double negation, it's a single negation. NotInactive would be closer to a double negation.

Answer (score 6):

Obfuscation by design?

Comment: Non-desobfucation by sorta-design  also known as NDeso_DesgnPoo

Answer (score 3):

Backward compatibility with existing databases?

Comment: Sorry Alex but are you being serious here?

Answer (score 1):

It's widely known as the "not-not-negative spaghetti confusion pattern" and was first mentioned 1972. ;-) SCNR

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is in the architecture, not in the specific naming of the data.  For instance, if you used an entity framework, then your entity for this table could declare a property called InActive, and it could use the Active column as the datastore.  As far as the outside world is concerned, the translation back and forth is transparent.